# Loading Image from volley inside RecyclerViewAdapter in Android

Tags: android, android-volley, android-adapter

What parameter should i pass inside `Volley.newRequestQueue()`. **Note i am using this in my RecyclerViewAdapter class**. See the code below **onBindViewHolder()**

Had it been in any activity i know `this` would be passed.

**RecyclerViewAdapter.java**

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {
    List<ListModel> myArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<ListModel> myArrayList) {
        this.myArrayList = myArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_row, parent, false);
        RecyclerViewHolder recyclerViewHolder = new RecyclerViewHolder(view);

        return recyclerViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ListModel listModel =  myArrayList.get(position);

        holder.videoID.setText(listModel.getVideoID());
        holder.title.setText(listModel.getTitle());
        holder.dateAdded.setText(listModel.getDateAdded());

        //

        String url = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/"+listModel.getVideoID()+"/0.jpg";
        if (url != null) {
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue();

            // Retrieves an image specified by the URL, displays it in the UI.
            ImageRequest request = new ImageRequest(url,
                    new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Bitmap bitmap) {
                            //imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                            holder.thumbnail.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        }
                    }, 0, 0, null,
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            //imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                        }
                    });

            queue.add(request);
        }
        //
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return myArrayList.size();
    }

    public static class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView videoID, title, dateAdded;
        ImageView thumbnail;

        public RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            videoID = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvVideoID);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            dateAdded = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDateAdded);
            thumbnail = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivThumbnail);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to load the images from network when it comes to calling onBindViewHolder.

**The performance based approach** you should be using is an AsyncTask to download all the images you require, store the images in a cached location and once everything is downloaded - then set the adapter for recycler view. At this point, onBindViewHolder should load the images.

Also, as a word of wisdom - before you set an image in onBindViewHolder, set the image source to null and then set the actual image you'd like. This optimizes the process of loading images in recycled view holders. (Remember, the user's impression is everything, do all in your power to give them a smooth scrolling experience).

Comment: @apelsociz
I am using Volley Library to load images. I think it already does the loading work in background thread. So it wont effect the user experience here.

Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Very well, I shall correct you. Lol! What I am attempting to emphasis is that you should be downloading the images before the Android system has even created the RecyclerViewAdapter. What your code does here is different - because it is deciding which image is required and doing the work to download only when onBindViewHolder is called. You should anticipate that these images are required and download them (to make them truly immediately available) before the adapter is created.

Comment: Notice in an example I have done previously, I am using the Picasso library, but to exemplify, I am specifying a `NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE` on line 85 https://github.com/apelsoczi/Popular_Movies/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/pelsoczi/popularmovies/ui/Adapter.java. You can also view line 180 from https://github.com/apelsoczi/Popular_Movies/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/pelsoczi/popularmovies/ui/MovieFragment.java, here I am downloading my data with an AsyncTask and once onPostExecute occurs I then update the recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

Passing `getApplicationContext()` from MainActivity and initializing the context in the RecyclerViewAdapter Constructor worked.

**MainActivity.java**

`recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(myArrayList, getApplicationContext());`

**RecyclerViewAdapter.java**

```
public RecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<ListModel> myArrayList, Context context) {
    this.myArrayList = myArrayList;
    this.context = context;
}
```